# Oracle Query: Where i have to set the RowNum Command

Tags: sql, oracle, join, rownum

I have an sql Statement and i don't know where i have to set the row num limit command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RELES.AKTJAHR,
            RELES.VORJAHR,
            RELFIRMA.NAME,
            RELFIRMA.KTXT,
            RELES.VORVORJAHR,
            RELFIRMA.FIRMANR,
            RELANSCH.STRASSE,
            RELANSCH.ORT,
            RELANSCH.LAND,
            RELANSCH.STAAT,
            RELANSCH.PLZORT,
            RELANSCH.PLZPOSTFACH,
            RELANSCH.POSTFACH,
            RELACP.VERTRETER2,
            RELACP.VERTRETER1,
            RELANSCH.LANDKNG
            FROM (((INFOR.RELFIRMA RELFIRMA
      INNER JOIN INFOR.RELADRESSE RELADRESSE
         ON (RELFIRMA.FIRMANR = RELADRESSE.FIRMANR))
     INNER JOIN INFOR.RELANSCH RELANSCH
        ON (RELADRESSE.ANSCHRIFTNR = RELANSCH.ANSCHRIFTNR))
    INNER JOIN INFOR.RELES RELES
       ON (RELES.DATENFELDER_1 = RELFIRMA.FIRMANR))
   LEFT OUTER JOIN INFOR.RELACP RELACP ON (RELFIRMA.FIRMANR = RELACP.MNR)
    WHERE (    RELANSCH.VERWENDUNG1 = 1
    AND (    (RELES.SATZART = 'UK' AND RELFIRMA.VERWENDUNG1 = 1)
         AND (RELES.AKTJAHR > 10000 OR RELES.VORJAHR > 10000)))
```

So can anybody tell me where i have to se t the row command for example this value:

```
where rownum <= 10;
```

regards john

Comment: What do you want to achieve anyhow? Just get 10 randomly chosen result records? Adding to this: DISTINCT is something rarely needed when writing queries straight-forward. You are looking for all RELES records with values higher than 10000 along with their associated company and all that company's addresses and relacps? How can there be duplicates that must be eliminated with DISTINCT? Is it the RELACP table that would lead to duplicate results?

Comment: Hello Thorsten I'm not responsible for the whole Select Statement i just  need limit command for the query. so i just need the  first ten records which gives me the result from the query or sth. like that

Comment: So 10 randomly chosen records from the query result? And it doesn't matter which ten? And it doesn't matter whether two query executions give you the same random ten rows or different? You are not supposed to get ten different companies (relfirma) or ten different addresses or ten different whatever, but only ten different result rows, which can all be the same company or the same address for instance?

Comment: The Field  Firmanr. has  unique values  so for my example it will be good to geht  the first 10 records from it.

Answer (score 1):

You must place the *rownum* limit as a filter on the final result set.

Therefore you should use the following structure:

```
SELECT *
FROM (< place your query here >)
WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to use a subquery or CTE:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from t
where rownum <= 10;
```

In Oracle 12c+, you can use `fetch` instead on your original query:

```
fetch first 10 rows only
```

Comment: Hello Gordon for what does the t stand for ? .. sorry but my knowledge about sql is less good as bad .. i just have the order to test the query against our crm so for testing i need some row limts ... thats all

Comment: @user1755592 . . . In this query, `t` is a common table expression, often abbreviated as a CTE.